# SqlAlchemy 'field' is an invalid keyword argument for <Model>

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model Post:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    row_id = db.Column('id', db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    uuid = db.Column('uuid', db.String(36), nullable=False, index=True)
    start_timestamp = db.Column('start_timestamp', db.TIMESTAMP, nullable=True)
    ...
```

When I call Post(uuid='12345678', start_timestamp=datetime.now())

SQLAlchemy raises 'uuid' is an invalid keyword argument for Post.

What could be possible error? and any solutions?

Comment: This error is raised if a keyword argument passed to the default constructor does not match an attribute on the model class.  Probably you have a typo somewhere; try to produce a [mre].

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks for your comment. But actual problem is 
`Post(uuid='some_value', network_id='some_other_value')`
works on dev environment but the same code raises 
`uuid is invalid keyword argument for Post` on Prod server.